# How to return the name of a form's highest parent

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have subform and sometimes it is opend with a parent form, and sometimes it is opened with a parent and a grandparent forms.

How can I find the name of the highest current parent of the subform?

Comment: What does it mean to close a subform?

Comment: Sorry, I either have it opened as described above where there is a parent and a grandparent. Or I have it opened with a form similar to Subform1 as a main form and Subsubform1 as a subform, in this case there is only one parent and no grandparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using events and not relying on a string of object hierarchies. So `subform` decides it needs to be closed and raises a `CloseRequested` event. Then whatever form opened `subform` can act on that. That action could either be to attempt to close itself (if it succeeds then great, it was the parent) or pass it along the chain.

This example below doesn't use events but will work to close the parent-est form when a button is clicked on the subform.

```
'command button on your subform
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = FindHighestAncestor(Me)
    DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name
End Sub

Public Function FindHighestAncestor(frm As Form)
    If IsHighestLevelForm(frm) Then
        Set FindHighestAncestor = frm
    Else
        If TypeOf frm.Parent Is Form Then
            Set FindHighestAncestor = FindHighestAncestor(frm.Parent)
        Else
            Set FindHighestAncestor = frm
        End If
    End If

End Function

Public Function IsHighestLevelForm(frm As Form) As Boolean
    Dim f As Form
    For Each f In Application.Forms
        If f.Name = frm.Name Then
            IsHighestLevelForm = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsHighestLevelForm = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is your only two scenarios you can do two things. Check if `Mainform` is open or check the `Parent` property of `Subform1`.